# Hacer deploy a una versión especifica

Tags: maven, google-app-engine

Estoy usando GAE, normalmente hago Deploy con un plugin para eclipse en donde me da la opción de indicarle a cual versión subirse, sin embargo quiero hacerlo por linea de comando, el comando es el siguiente :

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

Sin embargo quiero setearle el parámetro de "version", pero no sé como.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para resolverlo agregué el siguiente plugin en el pom:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.9.120.v20160803</version>
            <configuration>
                <gcloud_directory>/usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk</gcloud_directory>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Y ejecuté el siguiente comando :

```
mvn gcloud:deploy -Dgcloud.version=VERSION
```